# Mouse Keys - Initial jump size (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, keyboard

I am trying to determine a formula that would allow to calculate the exact amount of pixels a "CTRL-pressed Mouse Key movement" would cause the mouse cursor to move, based on some of the Windows input settings that control this. (For starters, I'm only interested in the jump size a single keypress performs, so no acceleration.)

By reading up on this (and by trial-and-error), I found that the following parameters influence the amount of pixels jumped:

- "Top Speed" (a.k.a. iMaxSpeed, a.k.a Maximum Speed): value between 10 and 360. This does not seem to be linearly influencing the jump size.
- "Mouse Speed": value between 1 and 20. This does seem to be linearly influencing the jump size.
- "Monitor scaling" (the value in "Display Settings > Scale and layout > Change the size of text, apps, and other items): This also seems to be linearly (and less important for my case)
- ... (Any others I missed?)

I also noticed that the first Mouse Key jump with the same settings often jumps a smaller amount of pixels compared to subsequent jumps (separate keystrokes, so not because of acceleration). How can this be explained/predicted?

Thx in advance

Comment: This is likely going to vary broadly based on drivers too. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by a Ctrl-pressed mouse key movement.

Comment: @music2myear As far as I'm aware, drivers wouldn't influence this, as your keyboard is not aware of you having mousekeys enabled or not, neither does it send mouse input, it's the OS that sees your keyboard input and translates it to native mouse input.
As to Ctrl-pressed: you have an option to use Ctrl to speed up and Shift to slow down your mousekeys. If you don't press Ctrl, your mouse jump is extremely small, with Ctrl you can achieve a big jump from the very first keypress.

Comment: What is Mouse Keys?

Comment: @music2myear A little weird you mention it's likely going to vary based on drivers when you don't even know what Mouse Keys are, no? Anyhow: accessibility feature that allows you to control the mouse with your keyboard (usually with the numpad)

Comment: Except in the headline, where everything is supposed to be capitalized, you don't capitalize "Mouse Keys" elsewhere in the question, making the assumption you're talking about a mouse function reasonable. You can use the EDIT button to make your question more clear and specific.